# Extract urls from string without spaces between

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
$urlsString = "http://foo.com/barhttps://bar.com//foo.com/foo/bar"
```

and I want to get an array like this:

```
array(
    [0] => "http://foo.com/bar",
    [1] => "https://bar.com",
    [0] => "//foo.com/foo/bar"
);
```

I'm looking to something like:

```
preg_split("~((https?:)?//)~", $urlsString, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Where PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE definition is:

*If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.*

That said, the above `preg_split` returns:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'foo.com/bar' (length=11)
  2 => string 'bar.com//foo.com/foo/bar' (length=24)
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong or any other idea?

PS: I was using [this regex](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611) until I've realized that it doesn't cover this case.

**Edit:**

As @sidyll pointed, I'm missing the `$limit` in  the `preg_split` parameters. Anyway, there is something wrong with my regex, so I will use @WiktorStribiżew suggestion.

Comment: `preg_split` takes four arguments, the third is the limit. You're passing the flags as limit. Flags are the fourth argument. Still, this won't produce what you're expecting. The `DELIM_CAPTURE` puts delimiters as elements by themselves, and your regex causes some ambiguity with delimiters (matches http:// as http:// and // (two separated delimiters))

Comment: Oh! you're right. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `preg_match_all` with the following regex:

```
'~(?:https?:)?//.*?(?=$|(?:https?:)?//)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lATVAd/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:https?:)?` -  `https:` or `http:`, optional (1 or 0 times)
- `//` - double `/`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break as few as possible up to the first
- `(?=$|(?:https?:)?//)` - either of the two:

  - `$` - end of string
  - `(?:https?:)?//` - `https:` or `http:`, optional (1 or 0 times), followed with a double `/`

Below is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/oC9ucT):

```
$urlsString = "http://foo.com/barhttps://bar.com//foo.com/foo/bar";
preg_match_all('~(?:https?:)?//.*?(?=$|(?:https?:)?//)~', $urlsString, $urls);
print_r($urls);
// => Array ( [0] => http://foo.com/bar [1] => https://bar.com [2] => //foo.com/foo/bar )
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one question: What does the first `?:` means?

Comment: See [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon).

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks again.