# Extract joined urls but not if redirect exists

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex for extracting urls when they are not separated by a space or whatever, but keep the "redirect" ones a a complete url.

Let me show you an example:

```
http://foo.barhttps://foo.bazhttp://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz
```

should result in the following array:

```
['http://foo.bar', 'https://foo.baz', 'http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz']
```

I am able to separate urls joined thanks to this regex :

```
'~(?:https?:)?//.*?(?=$|(?:https?:)?//)~'
```

from this answer: [Extract urls from string without spaces between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495572/extract-urls-from-string-without-spaces-between)

But I struggle to also extract the ones by keeping the `=http`

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using Python? Or which language?

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind that matches `=` to keep it from breaking those up.

Comment: Why do you have `~` at the beginning and end? Are you using PHP so it requires a delimiter around it?

Comment: I'm using python

Comment: How would you split `http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz?foo=bar&baz=quxhttp://`?

Comment: `['http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz?foo=bar&baz=qux', 'http://']` but in the redirect url, special characters should be encoded of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: for python

Use `re.split` and regex `(?<!=)(?<!^)(?=https?://)`.

It will split on beginning of new url, unless this new url preceded by `=`, or first in line (to exclude redundunt split in the beginning of string)

```py
>>> re.split(r'(?<!=)(?<!^)(?=https?://)', 'http://foo.barhttps://foo.bazhttp://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz')
['http://foo.bar', 'https://foo.baz', 'http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz']
```

Demo and explanation at [regex101](https://%20https://regex101.com/r/SXcK6o/2).

---

Assuming (based on regex provided in question) you are using PHP:

Use [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and lookahead for `https?://` and negative lookbehind with `=|^` to exclude matching beginning of URL preceded by `=` and redundant split in the beginning of line.

```php
<?php
$keywords = preg_split("~(?<!=|^)(?=https?://)~", "http://foo.barhttps://foo.bazhttp://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz");
print_r($keywords);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://foo.bar
    [1] => https://foo.baz
    [2] => http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz
)
```

Online demo [here](https://3v4l.org/GUkGa).

Demo and explanation at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SXcK6o/1).

Comment: I tried to use it with python: re.findall('(?<!=|^)(?=https?://)', 'http://foo.barhttps://foo.bazhttp://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz')
but got an error re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco, updated for python.

Comment: Yes with 2 separate lookbehinds it will work in Python

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I know. First version of the answer was based on the assumption that this is for php. I was to eager to answer before clearing all details(

Answer (score 2):

You could also update the pattern a bit to exclude a preceding `=` in the negative lookahead:

```
https?://\S*?(?=(?<!=)https?://|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XNiscB/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zV0ztC)

```
import re

pattern = r"https?://\S*?(?=(?<!=)https?://|$)"

s = ("http://foo.barhttps://foo.bazhttp://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz\n"
    "http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz?foo=bar&baz=quxhttp://")

matches = re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
[
  'http://foo.bar',
  'https://foo.baz',
  'http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz',
  'http://foo.bar?url=http://foo.baz?foo=bar&baz=qux',
  'http://'
]
```